Not able to host my application on render
I am not able to host my full stack web application on render.
When I try to run it locally it is running fine with zero errors and bugs.
But when I am deploying it on render, the deployment is successfull but on clicking the link a white page appears and no error or logs can be found.
Github Repo link: https://github.com/Sourz-101/Chat-App
Render Deployed Link: https://chat-app-npl5.onrender.com
I was expecting it to work on render link just as it was working on localhost.
But instend, reunder deployment is successfull but nothing is visible, Only a white screen is showing with no error or waring in the console page.
